# converting a list of shapely geometry to numpy array

Tags: python, shapely, numpy

How can I convert a shapely point geometry like following to numpy array?

```
[<shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x000001CEF6978DA0>, <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x000001CEF6978CF8>, <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x000001CEF6978E10>]
```

or in str:

```
['POINT (656822.0796426814 -185003.7243437266)', 'POINT (656917.7545657885 -184985.6672704536)', 'POINT (656997.7888963958 -185001.578684116)']
```

to a `numpy array` with `shape (3,2)`like this:

```
[[ 656822.0796426814 -185003.7243437266]
[ 656917.7545657885 -184985.6672704536]
[ 656997.7888963958 -185001.578684116]]
```

Comment: What have you already tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Not clear why this is marked as off-topic, has certainly seen a lot of visitors! At most one could possibly argue this is better housed in SO, but seems it could equally be here. Could a moderator-level user clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a shapefile with your point coordinates and the following code produces those numpy arrays:

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape
import numpy as np

path = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/points_list.shp' #your points

points = fiona.open(path)

geoms = [ shape(feat["geometry"]) for feat in points ]

list_arrays = [ np.array((geom.xy[0][0], geom.xy[1][0])) for geom in geoms ]

for array in list_arrays:
    print array
```

Result after running it is:

```
[ 656822.07964268 -185003.72434373]
[ 656917.75456579 -184985.66727045]
[ 656997.7888964  -185001.57868412]
```

Comment: Just for completion: if you want to have the coordinates in one big array, you have to define an empty one with arr=np.empty((0,2)) and then append it in the for loop with     arr = np.append(arr,np.array([array]),axis=0)

Comment: I think it is cleaner to do the following - `list_arrays = list(zip(*ls.xy))` Then there is no ambiguity with indexes and it is easier to read. Or if you need it to be a list of list, `list(map(list, zip(*ls.xy)))`

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of the coordinates and convert into a numpy array using np.array().

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
mypoints = [Point(1, 2), Point(1.123, 2.234), Point(2.234, 4.32432)]

listarray = []
for pp in mypoints:
    listarray.append([pp.x, pp.y])
nparray = np.array(listarray)

print mypoints
print nparray
```

Printed output:

```
[<shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x10f1bd350>, <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x10f1bd410>, <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x10f1bd3d0>]
[[ 1.       2.     ]
 [ 1.123    2.234  ]
 [ 2.234    4.32432]]
```